# Is there a way to load a json file from amazon s3 into a postgresql db instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, amazon-rds

So I have `.json` data file with nested objects which is stored on Amazon S3 and need to be loaded into an RDS for PostgreSQL DB Instance.

Upon investigation, i realized it works well with `.csv` data files.

How about `.json`?

Comment: There's no obvious way how to map a nested JSON file into a two-dimensional table…

Comment: I think the postresql db got a one-dimensional table linked with foreign keys